# On the strong convergence of generators and the corresponding semigroups

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, homogenization

Let $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ be a separable Hilbert space on $\mathbb{R}$. We consider a sequence of strongly continuous semigroup $\{T^{(n)}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ on $E$ [of course, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $t>0$, $T^{(n)}_t$ is a bounded linear operator].

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we write $(A_n,\text{Dom}(A_n))$ for the generator of $T^{(n)}=\{T^{(n)}_t\}_{t>0}$. That is,
\begin{align}
A_nf&:=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{T^{(n)}_tf-f}{t},\quad
\text{Dom}(A_n):=\left\{f \in E :  \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{T^{(n)}_tf-f}{t} \text{exists in }E\right\}.
\end{align}

**Question.**

Let $T=\{T_t\}_{t>0}$ be a strongly continuous contraction semigroup on $E$. Then, the corresponding generator  $(A,\text{Dom}(A))$ is a densely defined closed linear operator on $E$.

We now assume the following  conditions.

1. $T$ is a symmetric semigroup on $E$. In other words,  $(A,\text{Dom}(A))$ is self-adjoint on $E$.
2. For every $f \in \text{Dom}(A)$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $f \in \text{Dom}(A_n)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\|A_nf-Af\|=0$.

Under these conditions, can we show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|T_t^{(n)} f-T_{t}f\|=0$ for any $t>0$ and $f \in E$ ?

Note that each $T^{(n)}_t$ is not necessarily contractive. In my impression, such a result generally does not hold. However, I have no counterexamples.

Comment: If you have $\|T_t^n\| \le Me^{\omega t}$ with the same $M, \omega$, this is a version of Trotter-Kato approximation theorem. Are you asking if this is true without the above stability assumption?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you for your comment. Yes. I'm thinking of a situation where it's not immediately clear if the stability assumption holds.

Comment: Without the stability assumption there are counterexamples, but I do not know if they appear also in your specific situation. I know F. Kuhnemund, M. Wacker: The Lie Trotter formula dose not hold for arbitrary sums of generators, Semigroup Forum 60 (2000), 478-485.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune It is not immediately clear for me whether the sequence of semigroups in this paper converge to a symmetric semigroup. Anyway, thank you very much for the information.

Comment: That I do not know; however it is the only counterexample I know.